# Erros in implementing inlinenav in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jqgrid-php

i am using jqgrid with codeigniter.

i am implementing inlinenav using following snippet.

here is my code :

```
jQuery("#contactlist").jqGrid('navGrid','#contacttoolbar',{view:false,edit:false,add:false,del:false,search: false});
jQuery("#contactlist").jqGrid('inlineNav',"#contacttoolbar");
```

mr. justin ethier suggested me to update my minified jqgrid.js file

i have done so.....but now it leads me to another one error shown below :

`a.type is not a function`

`uncaught exception: CustomError: Error in protected function: )308`

one solution is leading me towards another problem ......

Helppppppp

Thnx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$.type was added to jquery in version 1.4.3.  I had the same trouble - I was running 1.4.1.  Please update your jquery to at least 1.4.3 and try again.